# How to access the "What's New" window in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

When opening the newly updated *IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition)*, a "What's New" page displayed in the editor space.

Unfortunately, I accidentally quit the app before finishing reading.

Is there some way to access that What's New page again?

Answer (score 0):

The *Help* menu has a dedicated menu item for that page.

Choose: `Help > What's New in IntelliJ IDEA`.

[image]